# Creating a string from a map

Tags: ruby

I'm currently working on a project where by using context free grammar rules, I will generate random sentences. Right now, I'm working on creating a function that will take in a hash, and traverse through it picking the correct productions to create a sentence and return it as a string.

For example, given a hash of the following format:

```
{
"<start>"=>[["The", "<object>", "<verb>", "tonight."]], 
"<object>"=>[["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]], 
"<verb>"=>[["sigh", "<adverb>"], ["portend", "like", "<object>"], ["die", "<adverb>"]], 
"<adverb>"=>[["warily"], ["grumpily"]]
}
```

I should be able to generate a random sentence, such as: "The waves die grumpily tonight".

Here is the overall process to generate this sentence:

1. It will always begin generating at the `<start>` tag and continue filling in the required productions.
2. It goes through `<start>` and adds "The" then comes across "`<object>`" so it goes into the `<object>` key and grabs a random value from there, such as `["waves"]`.
3. Then it goes back and continues traversing and comes across "`<verb>`" so it goes into the `<verb>` key and grabs a random value from there, such as `["die", "<adverb>"]`.
4. Since it encountered "`<adverb>`" it has to go into the `<adverb>` key and pick a random value, such as ["grumpily"].
5. Then it goes back to traversing, and comes across and adds "tonight". It has reached the end of `<start>` so it can output the sentence now.

How can I write a method to randomly generate the sentences?

Comment: Your question is premature. You're supposed to try, then when you can't figure it out show us how you tried to solve `# TODO: your implementation here` with a detailed question about the specific problem you encountered, instead of asking us how to write the code. “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”

Comment: I'm not asking for the solution, I'm learning ruby for 2 weeks now and am not familiar with how to go about it in ruby. If this were to be done in Java, I would not have as much trouble writing this function.

Answer (score 4):

Fun exercise!

After defining String#has_placeholder? to check for words between < and >

the algorithm picks a start sentence and iterates through it as long as there are placeholders. If a placeholder is found, it is replaced by a randomly picked subsentence.
Nothing is done to check for errors. Some placeholder could be undefined or there could be an infinite loop.

It returns a string, it could also return a tree with arrays of different depths.

```
class String
  def has_placeholder?
    self=~/<\w+>/
  end
end

grammar = {
  "<start>"=>[["The", "<object>", "<verb>", "tonight."]], 
  "<object>"=>[["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]], 
  "<verb>"=>[["sigh", "<adverb>"], ["portend", "like", "<object>"], ["die", "<adverb>"]], 
  "<adverb>"=>[["warily"], ["grumpily"]]
}


sentence = grammar["<start>"].sample.join(' ')

while sentence.has_placeholder? do
  puts sentence
  sentence.sub!(/(<\w+>)/){grammar[$1].sample.join(' ')}
end

puts sentence
```

It outputs :

```
The <object> <verb> tonight.
The slugs <verb> tonight.
The slugs portend like <object> tonight.
The slugs portend like slugs tonight.
```

or

```
The <object> <verb> tonight.
The big yellow flowers <verb> tonight.
The big yellow flowers portend like <object> tonight.
The big yellow flowers portend like slugs tonight.
```

EDIT:

The method you want could look like this :

```
def expand(grammar, nonterm = "<start>")
  sentence = grammar[nonterm].sample.join(' ')
  while sentence.has_placeholder? do
    sentence.sub!(/(<\w+>)/){grammar[$1].sample.join(' ')}
  end
  sentence
end
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a relic from Ruby 1.8 :D

Comment: Your code checks if a string is a placeholder (i.e. < is the first character, > the last one). My code checks if a string contains a placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick implementation where I use `symbols` instead of `<>` strings but you can change it to handle that if you want easily.

```
$grammar = {
  :start   =>  [["The", :object, :verb, "tonight."]],
  :object  =>  [["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]],
  :verb    =>  [["sigh", :adverb], ["portend", "like", :object],
                 ["die", :adverb]],
  :adverb  =>  [["warily"], ["grumpily"]]
}

def generate_sentence key
  return key if key.class == String
  $grammar[key].sample.map {|word| generate_sentence word}.flatten
end

3.times do
  puts generate_sentence(:start).join(" ")
end
```

It outputs:

```
The big yellow flowers sigh warily tonight.
The slugs die warily tonight.
The big yellow flowers portend like slugs tonight.
```

Comment: Is the 3.times loop inside the method declaration? I am trying to have one def expand(grammar, non_term="<start>") method to do the whole thing.

Comment: 3.times loop is just to get 3 different examples.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that all hash values are arrays and an element of those arrays is chosen randomly. If the randomly-selected element is an array, all words contained in that array are used in the sentence and any hash keys in that array are replaced by a randomly-selected element of the value of that hash key, and so on.

**Code**

```
def random_words(h, key)
  h[key].map { |obj| recurse(h,obj) }.join(' ')
end

def recurse(h, obj)
  case obj
  when Array
    obj.map { |o| recurse(h, o) }
  when /\<.+?\>/
    recurse(h, h[obj].sample)
  else
    [obj]
  end
end
```

**Examples**

*Example 1*

```
h = { "<start>" =>[["The", "<object>", "<verb>", "tonight."]],
      "<object>"=>[["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]],
      "<verb>"  =>[["sigh", "<adverb>"], ["portend", "like", "<object>"],
                   ["die", "<adverb>"]],
      "<adverb>"=>[["warily"], ["grumpily"]]
}

random_words(h, "<start>")
  #=> "The waves portend like slugs tonight."
random_words(h, "<start>")
  #=> "The big yellow flowers sigh warily tonight." 
random_words(h, "<start>")
  #=> "The slugs die warily tonight." 

random_words(h, "<object>")
  #=> "waves big yellow flowers slugs" 
random_words(h, "<verb>")
  #=> "sigh warily portend like waves die warily" 
random_words(h, "<adverb>")
  #=> "warily grumpily"
```

*Example 2*

```
h = { "<start>" =>[["The", "<object>", "<verb>", "tonight."]],
      "<object>"=>[["waves"], ["big", "<verb>", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]],
      "<verb>"  =>[["sigh", "<adverb>"], ["portend", "like", "<object>"],
                   ["die", "<start>", "<adverb>"]],
      "<adverb>"=>[["warily", "<object>"], ["grumpily"]]
}

random_words(h, "<start>")
  #=> "The big sigh grumpily yellow flowers die The waves sigh grumpily \
  #    tonight. grumpily tonight." 
random_words(h, "<start>")
  #=> "The big die The big die The slugs sigh grumpily tonight. grumpily \
  #    yellow flowers die The big sigh warily slugs yellow flowers die The \
  #    slugs die The slugs portend like big portend like big sigh grumpily \
  #    yellow flowers yellow flowers tonight. grumpily tonight. grumpily \
  #    tonight. warily waves tonight. warily big die The slugs sigh warily \
  #    big sigh grumpily yellow flowers tonight. warily big portend like big \
  #    portend like waves yellow flowers yellow flowers yellow flowers yellow  \
  #    flowers sigh warily waves tonight."
```

*Example 3*

```
h = { "<g1>"=>[["It", "<g2>", "<g3>", "..."]],
      "<g2>"=>[["of"], ["waves"], ["was the", "<g3>", "<g4>", "<g3>"],
               ["wisdom,"], ["foolishness,"]],
      "<g3>"=>[["<g4>", "of", "<g2>"], ["it", "<g2>"]],
      "<g4>"=>[["best"], ["worst"], ["age"], ["times,"]]
}

random_words(h, "<g1>")
  #=> "It of it was the it was the it was the times, of foolishness, times, \
  #    it wisdom, best best of was the it of times, it was the times, of of \
  #    best it waves worst age of waves ..."
random_words(h, "<g1>")
  #=> "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of  \
  #    wisdom, it was the age of foolishness...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sentence_generator(hash)
  verby = hash["<verb>"].sample.map do |string|
    string = hash[string].nil? ? string : hash[string].sample.sample
  end.join(" ")

  hash["<start>"][0][0] + " " + hash["<object>"].sample.sample + " " +  verby + " " + hash["<start>"][0][3]
end
```

This method should do the job for you. It could use some little refactoring, so you can look into that. I hope it helps

Comment: NP it was a fun one

Comment: Your example isn't dynamic, it it? It doesn't seem to use the sentence definition.