# Creating placeholder tags for dynamic variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I looking for a way to define a set of placeholder/merge tags or implement a DSL where a set of template tags used in a view file would be dynamically substituted for conditional variable values.

For instance the template may look like this:

```
The quick <<COLOR>> <<ANIMAL_1>> jumps over the lazy <<ANIMAL_2>>
```

And the output of course resulting in:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

This is beyond using <%= animal.color %> in an ERB template. In this case  a user should ideally be able to use these tags in a form input with the tag alias saved with the rest of the text in the database.

I'm not sure how to refer to these tags so here's an example from the Mandrill documentation on their own "merge tag" feature:  [How to Use Merge Tags to Add Dynamic Content](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582487-How-to-Use-Merge-Tags-to-Add-Dynamic-Content)

Are there any existing gems that can do this?  If not, how might I implement something similar?

Comment: How are `COLOR`, and `ANIMAL_1` defined?

Comment: They would be defined from model object attributes as associated by an individual record ID or collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an adapted version of a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40334144/6419007). Given a String and a Hash, the `expand` method just iterates with `sub` until no more placeholders are found.

```
class String
  def has_placeholder?
    self=~/<<\w+>>/
  end
end

wordbook = {
  "<<COLOR>>"=> "brown",
  "<<ANIMAL_1>>"=> "fox",
  "<<ANIMAL_2>>"=> "dog"
}

def expand(sentence, wordbook)
  while sentence.has_placeholder? do
    sentence.sub!(/(<<\w+>>)/){wordbook[$1]}
  end
  sentence
end

puts expand("The quick <<COLOR>> <<ANIMAL_1>> jumps over the lazy <<ANIMAL_2>>", wordbook)
#=> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

It is also possible to have nested placeholders :

```
wordbook = {
  "<<ADJECTIVE_1>>"=> "quick",
  "<<ADJECTIVE_2>>"=> "lazy",
  "<<COLOR>>"=> "brown",
  "<<ANIMAL_1>>"=> "<<ADJECTIVE_1>> <<COLOR>> fox",
  "<<ANIMAL_2>>"=> "the <<ADJECTIVE_2>> dog"
}

puts expand("The <<ANIMAL_1>> jumps over <<ANIMAL_2>>.", wordbook)
#=> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

If you're interested, the linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40334144/6419007) picked a string randomly out of multiple possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the suggestion. I've tested this in the app I have running and it seems to be working well thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the problem in depth, to me your question remains unclear: What is coming from the User when and what should be substituted by what (and how, by whom)? :)

Anyway, when speaking about **String substitution and templating**, sometimes **plain old ruby** is enough:

```
template = "The %{color} %{animal_1} jumps over the lazy %{animal_2}"
assignments = {color: 'black', animal_1: 'worm', animal_2: 'whitewalker'}
# pass Hash with substitution content
template % assignments #=> "The black worm jumps over the lazy whitewalker"
```

"String#%" is documented here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-25 .

But if you actually want a grammar, pick the other answer ;) . As stated, your question remains unclear to me.

Comment: Yes apologies I don't really know of any specific terminology for this so it is a bit unclear. The user would type the placeholder tag (i.e. <<COLOR>>) directly into a form input which is saved with the record in the db.  Services like MailChimp use a similar approach for their email templates where a user can enter tags such as <<EMAIL>>, <<USERNAME>>, etc. and it will populate these placeholders with actual values (from the model) when the emails are sent.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is many years later, but I came across this post, and now see it is built into Ruby. See here: https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/49-what-the-format.html#referencing-template-style

Hope this helps someone who stumbles here.